# How to set background image in asp.net by using c# in master page

Tags: asp.net

```
<body id="Body1" runat="server" style="background: url('imgBackThemeHomePage.jpeg'); background-repeat: repeat;">
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     </form>
</body>
```

I am unable to set background image with the above code.  Please tell me how to set background image in asp.net master page.

Answer (score -2):

move image to images folder and then just modify your code as

Its working